# Ionic 3: Build in “prod” mode: Cannot find module “.”

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

we have a large `Ionic` app that we’re trying to `build` in `production` mode since it’s almost ready. The first issue we found is that we were getting a “`JavaScript` heap out of memory” error when compiling, but we fixed it by giving more memory to node:

```
"ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=16384 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build",

npm run ionic:build -- --prod
```

With this command the app successfully builds, but if I open it I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module “.”
at vendor.js:1
at vendor.js:1
at Object. (vendor.js:1)
at e (vendor.js:1)
at Object. (main.js:1)
at e (vendor.js:1)
at window.webpackJsonp (vendor.js:1)
at main.js:1
```

I searched a bit and I found that it could be caused by `require`, but we aren’t using it. Any idea of what could be going on or what we can do to debug the issue? Is there any way to use “–-prod” without minifying the JS?

This is my environment:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0 
Gulp CLI              : [09:06:54] CLI version 3.9.1 [09:06:54] Local version 3.9.1
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.1.2 ios 4.3.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
ios-deploy        : 1.9.1 
ios-sim           : 5.0.8 
Node              : v8.6.0
npm               : 5.3.0 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.3.1 Build version 9E501 
Misc:

backend : legacy
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the problem. In my package.json I was using:

```
"typescript": "^2.9.1",
```

Decreasing the version to `~2.6.2` fixed it for me.

Comment: This shouldn't be considered a fix, but a workaround. I've been using `"typescript": "^2.9.2"` for sometime and in releasing a new version today, got this same error for ionic-cli 4.1.1.

Comment: In my project I cannot decrease the typescript version. Is there any other fix ?

Comment: Adding the initial symptom here hoping it gets properly indexed: I got here after my debug build was fine and the production build showed the splash screen then a black page; I enabled debug in the production build through AndroidManifest.xml and finally found this page.

Comment: I need typescript 3 for a dependency like rxjs. What's the cause of this problem? Downgrade the typescript version should not be the best solution. This error only occurs in prod build. (--release --prod)

Comment: @Dominik and exequielc have you found a solution since then ? I cannot decrease the typescript version

Comment: @Dominik sorry I Haven't found any fix yet. I run the app in dev mode

Comment: "Unfortunately" it did work to change "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3", "typescript": "2.9.2" to     "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4", "typescript": "2.8.3". But too bad it's not clear.

Answer (score 9):

Removing `^` from `@ionic/app-scripts` and `typescript` works for me as follows:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "typescript": "2.8.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, but the wrong `typescript` package was getting pulled in from a combination of other dependent projects as well as VS Code.  I resolved it by pinning the **exact** version (no `^` or `~`) of `@ionic/app-scripts` and `typescript` to what I needed.

`"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }`

Answer (score 2):

For me work using

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
"typescript": "2.7.1",
```

if do you want to use typescript v3, you can try to build disabling aot (that I think is the problem of using prod tag) with other adicional options

```
--release --aot false --environment prod --output-hashing all --sourcemaps false --extract-css true --named-chunks false --build-optimizer true --minifyjs=true --minifycss=true --optimizejs=true
```

If not, I recommend you to move to ionic4/5

Answer (score 1):

Got this error with a new version and I checked the ionic-angular imports and it's fine.

package.json

```
"typescript": "3.1.6"
```

Ionic info

```
 ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.4.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, browser 5.0.3
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)
```

error

```
vendor.js:138159 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (vendor.js:138159)
    at vendor.js:138159
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.js:138168)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:55)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:16031)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (vendor.js:26)
    at main.js:1
```

Comment: @exwquielc how did you reolved this?